# JavaScript generator, function* and array method forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use **forEach** array method as cycle inside generator instead of **for**.

So instead:

```
function* someFunction() {

  for (let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) yield someArray[i];

}
```

I want something like this:

```
function* someFunction() {

  someArray.forEach((a) => {yield a});

}
```

Problem: yield isn't is not allowed inside ordinary functions such as "forEach"

So question: what is the best and elegant way to Bypass that problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `for (let a of someArray) yield a`? (I'm assuming your real case is more complicated than shown, otherwise just `yield* someArray`.)

Comment: It is more complicated, but it is possible to use `for` in it. Idea was only to simplify code.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use `forEach` array method as cycle inside generator instead of for.

No, you don't.

You don't because you *can't*. It's literally impossible. Don't try.

What you *probably* want to do shorten the `for` loop to be more concise, especially when you already have an array or iterator.

The simple solution is to use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

```
function* someFunction () {
  yield* someArray
}
```

`yield*` will delegate iteration to the iterable you use it on, and is much more concise than attempting to use `.forEach`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I do. And it is even possible.

`yield* some Array` doesn't not allow you to call `yield` inside callback function.

But it is possible to do something like this:

```
 yield someArray.map((a) => {
            return function* (a){yield a}(a);
    });
```

Still it is not what I really want (simplify code), so probably it doesn't worth to do.